# save the output of window.print() and sent it to the server via ajax as a pdf

Tags: javascript, ajax, pdf, window, jspdf

I want to send the pdf generated with window. Print and sent it to the server with Ajax, and I can't use jsPdf because I need the pdf to be styled.

Can someone help?

Comment: The PDF generated by the browser `print()` method will be saved on the client file system, and you can't get it without asking the user to upload the file via a file `<input>` in another form.

Comment: i can't ask the client to upload it.

Comment: Well then, there is no way to do it. The browser generates the PDF file outside the Javascript sandbox, in order to be able to save it to the disk. Then, there is no way for Javascript to silently read it on the disk and send it to the server. That would be a huge security breach if JS could do that.

Comment: Have you tried using the `html` method of jsPdf?  https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-html.html

Comment: jsPdf generate a pdf with incorrect proportions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Keith propose you can use jsPdf set it like `new jsPDF("p", "pt", "a4");` and set fixed min-height of 840px and width of 600px when generating, before that you can use any sizes just make it responsive.

If you don't want to save it localy you can use `pdf.output("bloburl")` instead of `pdf.save()`

Also style must be applied at top level in your styles.

You can check this [generate-pdf-from-react-html](https://github.com/Milen-Minchev/generate-pdf-from-react-html#usage) about usage and correct proportions.